# Cloudinary image upload from React: am including Cloudinary unsigned preset but get "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, cloudinary

I'm trying to construct a simple Cloudinary image upload based on this codepen example: https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK --

I've converted it to work with `fetch` but even though I've gone to my Cloudinary settings and created an unsigned upload preset, which I'm providing to the headers, I'm still getting an error

`POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/myproject/upload 400 (Bad Request)`

with the error message

`Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload`

The code I'm using is the following

```
_callCloudinaryApi(file, method = 'post') {

    const config = {
      method
    }

    const cloudName = "myproject" // fictional project name here
    const unsignedUploadPreset = "mypreset" // fictional preset name here
    const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;


    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('upload_preset', unsignedUploadPreset);
    fd.append('tags', 'browser_upload'); // Optional - add tag for image admin in Cloudinary
    fd.append('file', file);


    if (method !== 'get') {
      config.headers = {}
      config.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

    return fetch(url, config)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
       console.log(res)
        return res;
      })
  }
```

Can anyone help me to determine what the problem might be?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like the following-

```
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('upload_preset', '<upload_preset>');
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('cloud_name', '<cloud_name>');

    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        body: data 
    };

   var imgurl = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/image/upload";

   fetch(imgurl, config)
    .then(responseData => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData, null, 4));
    })
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either -- still getting the same `400` error.  I even created a new preset but no dice.  I've gone to my Cloudinary settings, have `Unsigned uploading enabled` and have `unsigned` presets, which I'm using.  I tried an online example in which you enter your preset and it also didn't work.  Is there a waiting period of some kind before you can upload?  I created the account today.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too, going to `https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload`, you do have an `Upload presets` there, be sure that there is one with a `Signing Mode` turned to `Unsigned`.

It's maybe not the best thing to do in terms of security (better way will be to get authenticated I guess).

I found the clue about the 400 error with the Devtools network tab btw.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, hope this solution helps others

```
uploadFile = async (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', files[0]);
    data.append('upload_preset', 'PRESET_NAME');
    const res = await fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/{YOUR_ACOUNT_USER}/image/upload', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
    const file = await res.json();
    console.log(file);
    this.setState({
      image: file.secure_url
    })
  }
```